# xdmp:unquote function throwing SVC-FILSTAT error

Tags: marklogic

I am seeing a strange behavior of `xdmp:unquote` function in Marklogic `v10.0-7` version.

When ran the below code in `v10.0-3` it's working as expected while in `10.0-7` getting an error.

**Code:**

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:unquote('{"language":["http://www.google.com"]}')
```

**Error in v10.0-7:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `language` JSON property is "special":

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/languages#id_34181

> Any JSON content within a scope that contains a `language` or `lang` property is indexed in that language. Additionally, the `language` or `lang` property is inherited by all of the descendants of that element, until another `language` or `lang` property is encountered.

It is expected that a language code would be supplied.

This works just fine:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:unquote('{"language":["en"]}')
```

I am checking to see if the change in behavior for unknown languages is intentional.

Comment: Hi Madas, any update on the issue? I am also facing the same issue.